# Numpy std calculation: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to read lines of numbers starting at line 7 and compiling the numbers into a list until there is no more data, then calculate standard deviation and %rms on this list. Seems straightforward but I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rmscalc.py", line 21, in <module>
    std = np.std(values)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2817, in std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 116, in _std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 86, in _var
    arrmean = um.add.reduce(arr, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, keepdims=True)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

values = []
line_number = 6

road = '/Users/allisondavis/Documents/HCl'
for pbpfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(road, 'pbpfile*')): 
    lines = open(pbpfile, 'r').readlines()
    while line_number < 400 :
        if lines[line_number] == '\n':
            break
        else: 
            variables = lines[line_number].split()
            values.append(variables)
            line_number = line_number + 3
            print values

a = np.asarray(values).astype(np.float32)
std = np.std(a)
rms = std * 100
print rms
```

Edit: It produces an rms (which is wrong - not sure why yet) but the following error message is confusing: I need the count to be high (picked 400 just to ensure it would get the entire file no matter how large)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rmscalc.py", line 13, in <module>
    if lines[line_number] == '\n':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values` is a string array and so is `a`. Convert `a` into a numeric type using `astype`. For example,

```
a = np.asarray(values).astype(np.float32)
std = np.std(a)
```

Comment: how do you do that? can you provide some sample code?

Comment: I added an example, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: it did help, but I am having problem with the looping over the lines and getting all the information - it seems to be only reading from the first line, do you know how to fix this? I will edit my question

Comment: Answer to the edited question: You are iterating multiple files in your `for` loop, not within the file.

Comment: In your code, `file` is a list. If you have only on such file try `with open(file[0], 'r'), otherwise enclose `with` block in an outer `for` loop that iterates over all files in `file`